OpenIddict - Add JWT Token in Cookie after SignIn
I have an application which is an authorization service (AuthService). There are other services (WebApi, front) that should use this service for authorization and authentication. I use Identity + OpenIddict. In the authorization controller itself (AuthService) I call the standard method SignIn(principal,OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); and the controller gives me a JWT token in the response and it works in other API services.
But I need to return this JWT token in the cookie, how do I do that? Below is the code that shows what I want to do, but it doesn't work because the headers are read-only at this point.
var principal = await CreatePrincipalAsync(user);
principal.SetScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess);

//this is where the response is generated with the token
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

//this is where I get my answer.
var response = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerResponse();

//here I am trying to write the token generated by OpenIddict JWT to the cookie, but it is not possible
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", response.AccessToken,
new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(response.ExpiresIn) });


return Ok();

I realize that the problem is very simple, but I can't solve it.

Because the response headers of HttpContext.Response have already been written after SignInAsync is called, it is no longer possible to modify the response headers or add cookies.

Try to use AuthenticateAsync to implement this requirement, here is the sample code for you.

Thanks for your reply, but in my application there is no such signature of DispatchAsync method as described in your code. There is only this public async ValueTask DispatchAsync<TContext>(TContext context) where TContext : BaseContext

Hi D.Antov， as I said it's a sample code, I am willing to investigate the issue if you can share the demo repo( Please create a brand new sample project and hide your sensitive information ). Thanks~

why do you want to store the token unprotected in a cookie?
